# How to use multiple columns for texts in Excel

Tags: excel

I have multiple columns as follows

```html
A B C D Outcome
   Y Y
 N   N
    
N    N
Y    Y
```

My outcome is in the column E. If the cell is filled, I want to see it in the outcome column. If not I want to see a blank cell. I tried my best, but I could do it. Is there a simple function to do it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? What the result of your trial? Can there be more than one entry in A:D?

Comment: Edit your question to show the actual formulas that you tried, and what they produced with your data.

Comment: Also, show what you want for output if there are multiple entries in the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. One would be:

```
// Copy this down 
In Cell E2: =IF(COUNTA(A2:D2)=0,"",CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2))
```

Comment: Nice approach *(+1)* You may not need the test since if all the cells in **A** through **D** are empty, then `CONCATENATE()` will return a `Null` as well

Comment: Thank you! The first part of this, the counta(), looks to see if all are blank. If so, this returns "".

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
=A2&B2&C2&D2
```